# Darkice configuration to 2nd stream - password invalid

Tags: audio-streaming, shoutcast

Running Darkice on Ubuntu 14.04LTS with a audio source connected via mic input, from a mixer board which allows me to have a mic and audio source playing music.

With a single stream configured, it works:

```
[shoutcast-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr  
bitrate         = 224
quality         = 1    
server          = XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
port            = 8000       
password        = theP4ssw0RdisF4k3
name            = My Radio Station  
url             = http://urltowebsite
genre           = rock
public          = no
```

The above, when I run darkice works, and logs in with no problems.

I am trying to configure a 2nd stream to the same server, but I am unable to connect to it. So, I added the following below the [shoutcast-0] in my darkice.cfg file:

```
[shoutcast-1]
bitrateMode     = cbr      
bitrate         = 224
quality         = 1        
server          = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
port            = 8000     
password        = PassW0rdToSecondStream
format          = mp3
name            = Hawkwynd Radio - LIVE from The Greystone 
url             = http://stream.hawkwynd.com    
genre           = Classic Rock    
public          = no
```

Now, when attempting to run `sudo darkice -c darkice.cfg -v 10`:

```
DarkIce 1.0 live audio streamer, http://code.google.com/p/darkice/
Copyright (c) 2000-2007, Tyrell Hungary, http://tyrell.hu/
Copyright (c) 2008-2010, Akos Maroy and Rafael Diniz
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it 
under the terms of The GNU General Public License version 3 or
any later version.

Using config file: darkice.cfg
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 Using ALSA DSP input device: hw:1,0
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 encoding
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 scheduler high priority 99
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 Using POSIX real-time scheduling, priority 98
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 server response length:  20
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 server response:  OK2
icy-caps:11

X#n (   o   
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame mode 1
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame channels 2
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame in sample rate 44100
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame out sample rate 44100
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame bit rate 224
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame quality 0
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame lowpass frequency 0
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame highpass frequency 0
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame psycho acoustic model 1
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 set lame error protection 1
LAME 3.99.5 32bits (http://lame.sf.net)
CPU features: MMX (ASM used), SSE (ASM used), SSE2
Using polyphase lowpass filter, transition band: 19383 Hz - 19916 Hz
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 server response length:  18
23-Feb-2019 10:08:03 server response:  Invalid Password
S
?   o   ??o 
DarkIce: LameLibEncoder.cpp:75: lame lib opening underlying sink error [0]
```

The last 2 lines 'Invalid Password' most likely assumes the [shoutcast-1] stream is rejecting the password, which I have confirmed to be correct.

I used BUTT to connect to the 2nd stream while the 1st stream was running with darkice configured with only [shoutcast-0] section and BUTT connected ok using the legacy password. Legacy passwording 'password#1' is not possible to indicate in the darkice.cfg file.

So, my question is, how do I configure my darkice.cfg to successfully connect to both streams?